# How to print whole stack in C++ in without popping out elements and without loop?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

in Java we can print a stack like

```
Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>();
System.out.print(s);
```

How to do the same in C++, without popping element and without a loop?

Comment: You can't, that's not what stack is for. You can use `std::vector` directly if you need access to elements in the middle.

Comment: If you are talking about `std::stack`, there is no way.  You'd have to copy it and then loop through popping out elements to print

Comment: but we can do the same in Java .

Comment: @SachinRajput So? Java and C++ are two vastly different languages.

Comment: You're welcome to implement your own `Stack` class in C++ and override the `<<` operator, but `std::stack` doesn't. C++ is not Java.

Comment: @SachinRajput: That's because the JLS guys are not as smart as the C++ standards committee.

Comment: Java != C++.  Ether java is under the hood making a copy and doing the same thing, or it's print function knows about and can access the internals of the stack so it doesn't need to pop.  You would have to make your own stack and overload the output operator to do the same

Comment: See the specifications for [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack). There is nothing that satisfies your requirements, i.e, it can't be done. Perhaps the closest you can come is by creating a derived class to access the protected container member.

Comment: It would make sense to implement a class "debuggable stack" which behaves like `std::stack`, except when manipulated by a friendly "debug" class, which would be allowed to access all elements in the stack without popping them. Or a class "peekable stack" which only allow stack operations to modify it, but allows more operations when looking at it without modifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::stack` doesn't have any public function to let you iterate over it. But `std::stack` use `std::deque` as it's data structure:

- **GCC**:

  - https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_stack.h.html#98
- **MSVC**:

  - https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/stack#L21
- **Clang**:

  - https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/stack#L101

And it's a `protected` member, so you could inherit from `std::stack` and give access to its underlying data structure without the need to copy it. And `System.out.print(s);` eventually use a loop to iterate over `s` items and print it. You can do it in C++ by overloading `operator<<(std::ostream&, T const&)`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct my_stack final : std::stack<T>
{
    auto begin() const
    {
        return std::stack<T>::c.cbegin();
    }
    auto end() const
    {
        return std::stack<T>::c.cend();
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, my_stack const& in)
    {
        std::for_each(in.begin(), in.end(), [&out](auto const &i)
        {
            out << i << '\t';
        });
        return out;
    }
};

int main()
{
    my_stack<std::string> stack;
    stack.push("1");
    stack.push("2");
    stack.push("3");
    stack.push("4");

    std::cout << stack << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: nb: `for(...)` is a loop. So while it prints the whole stack, it doesn't meet the "without a loop" spec in the question. OP accepts this, though, so perhaps the specs are not written correctly.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson, You are right, sorry. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson the code could easily just replace the `for` loop with, for instance, `std::for_each()` or similar algorithm to handle the iteration.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Thanks, I edited my answer again. I thought `std::for_each` make the code looks complex.